# Cant pass an object as a message facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Maybe I am not understanding what I am reading in the docs 100% completely, I have just gotten into the facebook api today. I am trying to post a new item to my facebook feed from inside my app. This is the code I am executing.

```
function sendMessage() {
  var status = { name: 'Mike' };
  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', status, function(response) {
      if (response && response.id) {
          alert('Your post was published.');
      } else {
          alert('Your post was not published.');
      }
  });
}
```

This returns false and does not publish, the `status` returns an object, but obviously will not pass? If I post a string then it works.

```
function sendMessage() {
  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'test'}, function(response) {
      if (response && response.id) {
          alert('Your post was published.');
      } else {
          alert('Your post was not published.');
      }
  });
}
```

I learned this code mainly from the docs, but I saw in an example app "sociogram" they had code that passed an object, so I tried making my own function based on that.

So maybe I am missing the point but I would like to pass an object so that I can fill it with some dynamic data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`var status = { name: 'Mike' };`

do as in your latter, working, example

`var status = { message: 'Mike' };`

Comment: I think instead of an object I could just pass a string, but you are right you need `{message: 'here I can create a '+ dynamic.get('string')}` then I am just going to link to a webpage that contains the list of objects.